Book about a boy picking up a magic book that stabs him in a library
I read this book in the early 2010s, when I was 11 or 12. It was a physical book, no idea about the cover. I read it to my younger sister, and now we are looking for it.  It was a young-adult fantasy mystery book.
A boy with his sister, at a college. I think his dad was a professor. I think it was based in the late 20th century, not medieval for sure. I think the girl wore colored mud boots or a raincoat.
The boy finds a book that either has a thorn or a claw on it that stabs him and uses his blood to either unlock it or write in it. I can't remember if the book tells his story. I'm pretty sure a big chunk of it was missing and one of the professors was after him and the book, and maybe kidnaps his sister. And I think there was a dragon in a tree.

Do you remember if his sister was older or younger than him? And when you say "the book" in the second paragraph, are you talking about the book that stabbed him telling his story and having a chunk missing, or do you mean the physical book that you were reading?

There's an edit pending on this question from another user. @Emi if this user is you, please follow the instructions here to merge your accounts so you may edit this question directly.
